# Pyinstaller module not found error is occured. how to solve it?

Tags: pyinstaller

I use PyQt5, cv2, PIL, etc..

After working pyinstaller, exe file did not inculde them.

Error name is "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'".(Also, PyQt5, PIL...)

Then I fixed spec file to "hiddenimports=['PyQt5', 'PIL']", But it did not working too.

My python version is 3.7.(use pycharm.)
Pyinstaller is 3.5, 4.2, 5.0dev

How to solve this error?

I only used pycharm to install module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error accorded cuz of spec file overwriting, add hidden import as parameter when us create exe file of your script, such below

```
pyinstaller project/script.py --hidden-import=PyQt5
```

Comment: Already i used it. In spec file and pycharm.

Comment: i had this problem before, virtualenv and standalone python installed in my system, i config and ran my project using virtualenv but pyinstaller use standalone python that some package not installed there. install necessary packages on standalone python worked for me

Comment: so, if i install pyqt5 in shell (not in pycharm) by "pip3 install pyqt5", then working?
I'm not using vertualenv.

Comment: If this is your problem too, u must checking python versions and installed packages on them, then check pyinstaller used which python version. Generally the reason of this problem is uninstalled necessary packages in your python. I hope my tips are usefull for u :)